# Ruby on Rails creating HABTM relationship, currently getting Could Not Find Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

I am trying to change a `belongs_to` relationship to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. Here are the migrations I have tried:

Migration1

```
class RemoveSyndicateMemRef < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_reference :syndicate_members, :syndicate

    create_table :members_syndicates, id: false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :syndicate
        t.belongs_to :syndicate_member
    end
  end
end
```

Migration 2:

```
class MultipleSyndicatesPerUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :members_syndicates

    create_table :members_syndicates, id: false do |t|
        t.references :syndicate, null: false
        t.references :syndicate_member, null: false

    end

  end
end
```

When I try to use any of the HABTM methods I keep getting a

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'syndicate_members_syndicates'
```

error.

I'm relatively new to Rails so I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

After I fixed the name of the db table running `> syn.syndicate_members.build()` returned:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `syndicate_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table name does not meet Rails' naming conventions. To name a join table you should join the other table's name in alphabetical order.

In this case ´syndicate_members_syndicates´, since your tables are named `syndicate_members` and `syndicates`.

You can fix that by:

- You can revert your migration, change it from `create_table :members_syndicates` to `create_table :syndicates_members_syndicates` and run it again. That would fix the table name.

or

- You can add `:join_table => 'members_syndicates'` to both `has_and_belongs_to_many` declarations in the `Syndicate` and the `SyndicateMember` model. That tells Rails not to use the autogenerated name as a table name but `members_syndicates`. In this case you do not need to change the table name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't completely understand the solution you're suggesting. Can you clarify how you would change the migration?

Comment: @apardes Updates my answer, hope it helps. Do you have a specific question or problem?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that fixed that issue but presented another. I've updated my question with the new error.

Comment: Can you please post our models (at least the `belongs_to`, `has_one`, `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` declarations)?